# Como fazer que apenas um usuário tenha acesso a activity?

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, android-activity

Preciso de uma ajuda de vocês pois estou com uma dificuldade em fazer com que apenas um usuário tenha acesso a uma determinada activity.

Ex: 
Estou desenvolvendo um App onde a tela de configurações apenas eu terei acesso com meu usuário, nenhum outro. 
Quero deixar isso configurado no código apenas o meu userId com acesso a tela.

```
private void openRestrictedSettings() {
    if(userId.equals("id")){
        Intent intentRestrictedSettings = new Intent(TelaPrincipalActivity.this, ActivityRestrictedSettings.class);
        startActivity(intentRestrictedSettings);
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Apenas usuários autorizados podem acessar as configurações", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O "userPermissions" existe apenas em meu usuário, nenhum outro terá isso.

Como posso fazer para que uma activity abra apenas quem possui o userPermissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algumas coisas que pode tentar:

### Constantes.java

```
public final class Constantes {
    // TODO: Revisar o ID 
    public static final String UID_ADMIN = "dGVzdGVAdGVzdGUuY29t";

    private Constantes() {
        // Sem instâncias
    }
}
```

### Função para abrir a tela

```
private void openRestrictedSettings() {
    if (allowRestrictedSettings()) {
        Intent intentRestrictedSettings = new Intent(TelaPrincipalActivity.this, ActivityRestrictedSettings.class);
        startActivity(intentRestrictedSettings);
    }
}

private boolean allowRestrictedSettings() {
    /*
        Supondo que há um sistema de login com firebase
        e que você já tem uma classe UserEmail com o campo "id"
        e um objeto dessa classe disponível para verificação
     */
    FirebaseUser currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if (currentUser == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Por favor, faça login com sua conta", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }

    String userId = userEmail.getUid();
    String userPermissions = userEmail.getuserPermissions();

    if (!userId.equals(Constantes.UID_ADMIN)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Apenas usuários autorizados podem acessar as configurações", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userPermissions) || !userPermissions.equals("admin")) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Apenas usuários autorizados podem acessar as configurações", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }

    // Ou direto pelo firebase auth
    if (!currentUser.getUid().equals(Constantes.UID_ADMIN)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Apenas usuários autorizados podem acessar as configurações", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!!
Deu certo :)